# App delegate features in viewcontrller - Facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have a sample code with a header and an implementation file and the two appDelegate files. I would like to add what the project does to my app. The first two files are a ViewController file, so I just need to drag it in, but the other two are AppDelegate, and I obviously can't have two app delegate. But in the case of this sample app the app delegate is used as a proper viewcontroller, because in the .m file of the UIViewController file, there is this code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Since the AppDelegate doesn't implement methods such as applicationWillBecomeActive:, how can I transform the file into a UIViewController file? What do I need to change in the code above to call the controller, instead of the Delegate (my AppDelegate will so remain untouched).

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/SendRequestsHowTo)

This is what I have done (the code needs the Facebook API to be included). Go on the download tab and download Archive.zip and AppDelegate.zip: https://github.com/Alexmitico45/FacebookRequests/downloads

Basically the controller ContactFBSViewController is linked the a viewcontroller in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppDelegate is the singleton that implement the protocol UIApplicationDelegate, because so you can't duplicate it, it must be unique.
You can create your own singletons to store the info available all over your app. 
You can google "objective-c singleton" and get some good link to do it

Comment: Yes, but I would need you to check the code personally. download it from ghub and see what I have done

Comment: I'm sorry for you but this isn't a free debug service, I will never download your code on my pc. Te lo traduco in Italiano, qui nessuno ti farà mai il debug gratis,

Comment: sai come, sono un principiante, ho fatto il lavoro, e non riesco ha risolvere il problema. ci ho speso su giorni, non è che pubblico le cose per divertimento

Comment: Non puoi pretendere che un altro faccia il lavoro tuo, io lavoro e il mio tempo lo uso per risolvere i miei problemi, sei tu che devi cercarti in rete la soluzione, io ti ho solo dato una dritta, a questo serve stackoverflow.

Comment: hai ragione, ma il punto è che ho gia provato a usare singleton e non funziona lo stesso. se sapessi esattamente qualè il problema cercherei su quello, ma non sapendo qualè devo fare una domanda 'aperta'